# Prove That If $(a + b)^2 + (b + c)^2 + (c + d)^2 = 4(ab + bc + cd)$ Then $a=b=c=d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the following equation holds

$$(a + b)^2 + (b + c)^2 + (c + d)^2 = 4(ab + bc + cd)$$

Prove that $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are all the same.

What I did is I let $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ all equal one number. Then I substituted and expanded. I'm sort of proud of my self (first proof I done). I'm wondering, is there another way?

(I'm teaching my self maths and I'm only a humble precalc student)

Comment: Sorry, but setting $a=b=c=d$ proves nothing; what you have to do is the converse: if that equality holds, then all four numbers are equal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following steps

$$\begin{align}
(a + b)^2 + (b + c)^2 + (c + d)^2 &= 4(ab + bc + cd) \\
\left[ (a + b)^2-4ab \right] + \left[ (b + c)^2-4bc \right] + \left[ (c + d)^2-4cd \right] &=0 \\
\left[ a^2+b^2+2ab-4ab \right] + \left[ b^2+c^2+2bc-4bc \right] + \left[ c^2+d^2+2cd-4cd \right] &=0 \\
\left[ a^2+b^2-2ab \right] + \left[ b^2+c^2-4bc \right] + \left[ c^2+d^2-4cd \right] &=0 \\
(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-d)^2 &=0
\end{align}$$

and the sum of three **positive numbers** is zero if and only if they are all zero. So you will get

$$a=b=c=d$$

Comment: Is it possible to do the above but instead of step 2, you leave (a+b)^2...(c+d)^2 as is in brackets and subtract 4ab....4cd separately? Why did you bracket them together? eg you bracketed (a+b)^2 with -4ab but not with -4bc...it seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: @ElbertAinstein: Yes you can do it without step 2. The reason I bracketed them together is to give you the vision for seeing the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

$$(x+y)^2-4xy=\cdots=(x-y)^2$$

Now for real $z, z^2\ge0$

Comment: This only has two variables (x,y). The above has 4 variables (a,b,c,d). Can you elaborate on your thought process?

Comment: @ElbertAinstein, Replace $x,y$ with $a,b; b,c; c,d$ one by one